# Functions of vectors and vectors of functions

Tags: matrix-calculus, neural-networks

In page 22 of the [Matrix Calculus For Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01528), the authors wrote: It is the nature of neural networks that the associated mathematics deals with *functions of vectors* not *vectors of functions*. Did it mean f(x1, x2, ..., xn) as opposed to (f1(x), f2(x)..., fn(x))? Can you give a relevant example of (f1(x), f2(x)..., fn(x))? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what it meant.  As to your second question, I'm not familiar with neural networks but I think the answer is that there is no relevant example.  Isn't this just what your quoted passage is saying? - functions of vectors are relevant, vectors of functions are not.

Comment: @David. Thanks for confirming what I thought it was. Is just that I'm not well versed in both Maths and Neural Networks so I want to check my understanding on the text. I was wondering why the authors introduced that concept of vectors of functions?

Comment: It certainly sounded like something like that - e.g., $f (v_1, v_2)$, where $v_i$ are vectors: for instance $f(v_1,v_2) = v_1\cdot v_2$, the dot product of the $v_i$. Without reading, I had thought the point was that $f$ should take values in the reals. However, on p.24, the function ${\bf x}\mapsto\max(0,{\bf x})$ is a vector-valued function.  So I guess it's a matter of interpretation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In neural networks we generally have multiple inputs entering a perceptron and one output. Therefore, the output is a function of the inputs, e.g. $f(x_1,..,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_ix_i$ where the $w_i$ are the weights associated to each input. Here the multiple inputs can be seen as a single vector of inputs, thus, $f$ is a function of a vector.

A vector of functions occurs when one input parametrizes a set of outputs. We see this in parametric curves. For example $f(x)=(\cos{x}, \sin{x})$ parametrizes a circle.

Comment: As you actually seem to know something of the topic, you might have something to add to my comment above?

Comment: or to contradict in my comment above...

Comment: @John Douma, as I don't have enough math knowledge to say positively, but logically your answer makes sense, thus I'm going to accept it as an qualified answer. Thankyou!

Comment: @Jason If you are unsure you should un-accept this answer and give someone else a chance to answer. You may get a better answer.

Comment: @JohnDouma, I understand where you're coming from. Unfortunately due to my limited knowledge, I might not be able to know if other answer would be a better one. I'd therefore like to keep yours as the answer and leave it for the community to confirm my belief.